# Bind Socket Android

Tags: android, sockets, bind, ipv4

I have a problem on android. I have an application that asks the user for the local Ip address (from the device's interface) and another remote address. The application has to bind to the specified local address and connect to the remote address. Quite simple, but, indeed, bind does not work ass i expected..

I added the following permissions on the manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

The source code is the following one:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
String Tag = "TAG";
private int LOCAL_PORT = 4444;
private int REMOTE_PORT = 80;
private EditText LOCAL;
private EditText REMOTE;
private Button Connect;
private TextView STATUS;
private Context context = this;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);   


    LOCAL = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    REMOTE = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Connect = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    Connect.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            BotleneckHandle WORK;

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Proceeding to connect",
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        /*  
            if(LOCAL.getText().toString() == null || REMOTE.getText().toString() == null || LOCAL.getText().toString().equals(" ") || REMOTE.getText().toString().equals(" ") || LOCAL.getText().toString().equals("") || REMOTE.getText().toString().equals(""))
                Toast.makeText(context, "Wrong parameters", 2000);
            else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Proceeding to connect",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }*/

            WORK = new BotleneckHandle();       
            WORK.execute();
        }
    });

    STATUS = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
}


 private class BotleneckHandle extends AsyncTask <Void , Void , String>
 {
     Socket Skt = null;
     String ReturnStatemente = new String();
     SocketAddress localAddr = new InetSocketAddress(LOCAL.getText().toString(), LOCAL_PORT);

    protected void onPreExecute(){  }
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {

        try 
        {

            String s=new String();

            s+= "Local="+LOCAL.getText().toString()+":"+LOCAL_PORT+"  Remote="+REMOTE.getText().toString()+":"+REMOTE_PORT;  //so far so good, Confirmed by debug

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //Does not show anything due the fact that i didn't published it as an assync task update.. 

            //binding to a local address
            Skt.bind(localAddr);            //cannot make the bind :-/

            //connecting to remote host
            Skt=new Socket(REMOTE.getText().toString(), REMOTE_PORT);   //if bind is comment, still does not work.. I bet
            ReturnStatemente = "Connected";

        } 
        catch (UnknownHostException e) 
        {   
            e.printStackTrace();
            Toast.makeText(context, "Unknown remote host", 2000);
            ReturnStatemente = "Not Connected";
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {   
            e.printStackTrace();        
            Toast.makeText(context, "Connection fail", 2000);   
            ReturnStatemente = "Not Connected";
        }
        finally{try {
            Skt.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }}
        return ReturnStatemente;   

    }

    protected void onPostExecute(String result)  {    STATUS.setText(" CONECTION STATUS == " + result);    }



  }
```

}

What am i doing wrong on bind? As far as i see, and as i searched for its good.. Did i miss something?

kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to call bind on a variable before you assigned anything to it.  So its still null.  That isn't going to work.  You need to create an instance of Socket before you can call methods on it.